# Formula To Validate Text Formula?

Tags: formula, formula-field, validation, validation-rule, cross-object

I have created a formula field on the custom object. I tried to create this formula:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Final_Result__c ), ISPICKVAL(Lead_Status__c, "Admitted"))
```

where lead status is another formula field I created. The above gave me the error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text

How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 1):

You can check equality with a single equals sign (`=`). For text formulas, this operator should suffice:

```
Lead_Status__c = "Admitted"
```

The double equals sign (`==`) will also work, and some may prefer that stylistically although I do not. From [Formula Operators and Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/customize_functions.htm):

> **Operator**
> = and == (Equal)
>
> **Description**
> Evaluates if two values are equivalent. The = and == operator are interchangeable.